# Expected running time value of a random algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time

[image]

Given this algorithm, I am required to :
Find the recursion formula of the expected value of the running time.
Find the closest upper bound as possible.

I am actually a bit lost so if someone could help...

Comment: It is linear time O(n) up to a factor.

Comment: Where did you get stuck writing down the recursive formula for the expected running time? It's not so difficult to write down, and certainly a lot easier than actually solving it!

Comment: As a hint, you might check out an analysis of the expected running time of quickselect. It's not identical to your algorithm, but it shares many features in common, and the recursive formula and its solution will be similar.

Comment: @PaulHankin since there are multiple options at each iteration, i could bound with the worst/best cases but didnt succeed to write an explicit general formula

Answer (score 0):

Recursive formula for worst case: `T(n) = T(n/2) + n`

Recursive formula for best case: `T(n) = T(1) + n`

Recursive formula for expected case: `T(n) = T(n/4) + n`

Worst case: `2n = O(n)`

Best case: `n = O(n)`

Expected case: `4n/3 = O(n)`

---

Some people here seem to be confused about the `log(n)` factor. `log(n)` factor would only be required if `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n` i.e. if the function was called TWICE recursively with half the input.

Comment: I understand what you said and i thought about something similar, the thing is I need to find an explicit formula for the expected value of runnng time and that is the most problematic point

Comment: @BinyaminRiahi Sorry, not sure what exactly it is that you are asking for when you say "an explicit formula for the expected value of running time".